# Razor doesn't understand unclosed html tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

With RazorViewEngine, I can do this:

```
if (somecondition) {
     <div> some stuff </div>
}
```

but I can't seem to do this (Razor gets confused):

```
if (somecondition) {
    <div>
}

if (someothercondition) {
    </div>
}
```

I have a situation in which I need to put my opening and closing html tags in different code blocks - how can I do this in Razor?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if (somecondition) {
    @:<div>
}
```

Comment: or `<text><div></text>` - http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Comment: `<text><div></text>` works, but `<text></div></text>` does not.

Comment: @Stuntman you need to do this for both the opening and the closing tags to make it work.

Comment: and how to deal with multiline text?

Comment: I could not do this inline.  if(condition){@:tag}.  I had to format it like above.

Comment: If this gets much more complex I end up outputting content inside a string, razor sucks at conditional tag opening / closing within a loop.

Answer (score 63):

To explain Darin's answer, i.e prefixing the HTML like this:

```
@:<html>
```

@: in Razor means 'render something as plain text'

or you can use this, which outputs the HTML as you orginally wrote it (this can also be used to avoid the automatic HTML encoding that Razor does if you're trying to output HTML):

```
@Html.Raw("<html>")
```

(Html.Raw reference from MS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: solutions are great, but explanations are invaluable. thanks!

Comment: I prefer the @Html.Raw("<html>") solution, because the first one was split on multiline when using auto formatting (ctrl+K ctrl+D)

Comment: @MatteoSganzetta True unless what you are outputting has Razor variables sprinkled into it, for example: `@:<a href="@link" class="@classNames">@text</a>`

Comment: Be carefule using `@Html.Raw()` - [see related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381945/175679)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom MVC Helper method. For with you create a public static class MyRenderHelpers in namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Html` and write a method Html.

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class MyRenderHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString Html(this HtmlHelper helper, string html, bool condition)
        {
            if (condition)
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(html);
            else
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this extension method in your razor view:

```
@Html.Html("<div>", somecondition)
```

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you have to do this usually indicates that your view code is not factored correctly. The nature of HTML is to have balanced or self-enclosed tags (at least in HTML 4, HTML 5 seems to be leaning away from it) and Razor depends on that assumption. If your going to conditionally ouptut a `<div>` then you will also somewhere later output `</div>`. Just put the whoel pair in your `if` statement:

```
@if(something) {
    <div>
        Other stuff
    </div>
}
```

Otherwise you end up with weird code like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781896/razor-view-engine-complex-looping-and-html/4786195#4786195).

Comment: My situation is that I want to

Comment: Right, my point is that in 99% cases you probably shouldn't. But you might fit into that 1% in which case there's `@:` or `<text></text>`

Comment: he probably has a closing block later : `if (somecondition) { @:</div> }`

Comment: yes, he has to. my point is that such views can be refactored so that such dual conditionals are not necessary.

Comment: Not easily for this scenario `@if(true) { <link rel="stylesheet" href="some.css"> }`

Comment: @michielvoo in this case you should close the tag: `@if(true) { <link rel="stylesheet" href="some.css" /> }`

Comment: @michielvoo Why is it bad to use this method to have a conditional div wrapper for example? Also in HTML5 you do not close `<link>` tags.

Comment: If you need to have html tags conditionally wrapping certain frame depths during a recursive method as it unwinds, I think you need to be able to do this - at least I haven't figured out another way.

Comment: Late comment, but since it has a vote and is therefore showing: "Also in HTML5 you do not close <link> tags." Actually, in 8.1.2.1 #6 of https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/syntax.html#elements-0 it states that "Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/)." Void elements, as noted in 8.1.2 Elements, include `link`. So you don't have to close them, but you can, as long as you do so in the start tag.

Comment: Surely there are circumstances where what is desired is legitimate. You might want to bold certain stuff conditionally - where the "stuff" is included either way, but the start and end bold tags are conditional. As long as it's the same condition, that should be fine, surely

Comment: So how do I create a table of images, say 2 images wide, out of an array of images ?  A. foreach loop with a counter and when (counter %2 == 0) close the row and start a new row.  And if you're using a table razor compiler complains because there is no '<tr>' tag before the <td> tag.

Comment: @marcind: I had to do two different views because, I tried hard to do a conditional generation of the initial `<div>`s block and the final `</div>`s block, but I always got errors or things not working. In PHP, I could easily do this without duplication. So after all this contributes to worse code factoring.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the code in your answer is more readable. But also agree with some commenters. Sometimes you have a big complex LINQ as the data source. and writing "clean" HTML code like that would require doing a complex `GroupBy` over that source. I had a huge (!) performance bottleneck because of this, as LINQ is evaluated *on the go*. Having an option to render "header" and "footer" inside the main iteration solves it.