# Razor engine, placing a close tag

Tags: razor

The razor engien have been bugging me a bit today. I have to set a variable lastAnime = c.Anime.Name but i just get the error

> No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

```
 @{ var lastAnime = ""; }
<select name="character">
    <option value="">All</option>
    @foreach (var c in Model.Characters) {
        if (lastAnime != c.Anime.Name) {
            @{lastAnime = c.Anime.Name;}
            <optgroup title="@c.Name">
        }
        if(lastAnime != "") {
            </optgroup>
        }
        <option value="@c.Id">@c.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Answer to the question stated in the title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809694/razor-doesnt-understand-unclosed-html-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to look like this: (take out the @ block around your assignement statement)

```
    if (lastAnime != c.Anime.Name) {
        lastAnime = c.Anime.Name;
        <optgroup title="@c.Name">
    }
```