# Why is the HtmlHelper instance null in a Razor declarative @helper method?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

Using MVC 3 RTM I'm getting a strange `NullReferenceException`:

```
@helper TestHelperMethod() {
    var extra = "class=\"foo\"";
    <div @Html.Raw(extra)></div>
}
```

It turns out that `Html` (of type `HtmlHelper`) is `null`.

I've never seen this before in a regular view.  I'm starting to experiment with declarative helper methods in Razor (so far they seem a little limited) and I'm quite stumped by what I'm seeing here.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's a [known limitation of those helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451287/razor-declarative-html-helpers/4453637#4453637). One possibility is to pass it as parameter:

```
@helper TestHelperMethod(HtmlHelper html) {
    var extra = "class=\"foo\"";
    <div@html.Raw(extra)></div>
}
```

Another possibility is to write the helper as an extension method:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString TestHelperMethod(this HtmlHelper)
    {
        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.AddCssClass("foo");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(div.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.TestHelperMethod()
```

Comment: Thanks Darin.  Actually I was trying to convert from a helper method in code to a declarative helper.  They are so very promising, but this limitation and the inability to use type arguments is a real shame.  From the code in my answer I wonder whether a simple change to the `Html` property getter might provide this support.  `WebViewPage` has an `HtmlHelper<object>` property which could be read and returned.

Comment: 参数 1: 无法从“System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<XXX>>”转换为“System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper” :(

Comment: how to call this "TestHelperMethod(HtmlHelper html)" from View??

Comment: @PraveenPrasad, I see no one ever answered your question. This is a little late, but, to call his first solution (declarative helper) you would pass the local instance of the "System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper" object from your calling code as: TestHelperMethod(Html). Be sure to fully qualify the namespace as "HtmlHelper" exists in 2 namespaces as mentioned above and seems to default to the wrong one (at least it did in my code).

Comment: Hi! I have created an idea in ASP.NET user voice related to this: [Support @helper ExtensionMethod(this HtmlHelper html) for views in APP_CODE](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3670180-support-helper-extensionmethod-this-htmlhelper-ht)... help is appreciated in making it come to the front-lines... Thanks!

Comment: @Darin then with the first solution, how can we pass it to helper class

Answer (score 42):

Using [Drew Noakes suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5282713), I have come to a workaround that does the trick for now and that can be easily removed once the issue is solved in a newer version of MVC (that is if more stuff isn't changed that would break it:))

The goal is to be able to use an HtmlHelper inside a declarative helper method that lives in a file in App_Code without having a NullReferenceException. To solve this I included in all the files in App_Code the following:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;

@functions
{
    private static new HtmlHelper<object> Html
    {
        get { return ((WebViewPage)CurrentPage).Html; }
    }

    private static UrlHelper Url
    {
        get { return ((WebViewPage)CurrentPage).Url; }
    }
}
```

This does seem to do the trick as I can now write the following helper (in the same file):

```
@helper PrintAsRaw(string htmlString)
{
     @Html.Raw(htmlString)
}
```

Obviously the helper method is just an example. This solution has the downside that the @functions declarations has to be introduced in all helper declaration files in App_Code, but does avoid complicating the call to the helper, as you can simply write in a view:

```
@MyAppCodeFile.PrintAsRaw("<p>My paragraph</p>")
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Great, I look forward to giving this a try.  Are there any downsides you've found to this approach?

Comment: No, not yet at least... I've also applied the same idea for the UrlHelper and I can now call the UrlHelper methods in the delegate helper methods. Let me know if you encounter anything strange.

Comment: It seems I found a problem with this approach, at least when using the UrlHelper. Obviously @marcind knows better when he says that the HtmlHelper is not the same in that case, which I suppose is true for the UrlHelper as well. Anyway, using the UrlHelper gave me a NullReferenceException in the method System.Web.Mvc.UrlRewriterHelper.WasThisRequestRewritten(HttpContext). It seems that the ServerVariables collection that is obtained through the HttpContext of this UrlHelper is not the same as the usual ServerVariables collection (that does not throw that exception)...

Comment: Another advise: Include in the app_code file a using to the System.Web.Mvc.Html namespace, in order to call all the rest of the extension methods. Still no luck with the Url generation problem though :(

Comment: This worked for me - allowed me to call a compiled helper via a declarative helper when I added this function declaration to the top of the declarative helper.

Comment: Very nice!  Saved me some grief.

Answer (score 26):

I know it's not the point but if it is just `Html.Raw(value)` you were hoping to use when finding this question on Google (as I was) according to the source code of System.Web.Mvc.dll all Html.Raw does is:

```
public IHtmlString Raw(string calue)
{
    return new HtmlString(value);
}
```

So I've just used `@(new HtmlString(value))` in my helper which works nicely.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest solution.

Comment: Nice! I've used it to write my helper to use in my helpers :) - `@helper Raw(string value) { @(new HtmlString(value)) }`

Comment: 2017 and this issue still exists, using your method it works brilliantly.

Comment: 2018 and still kickin' it, worked perfectly! This helper is the way to go - was getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` using `Html.Raw`

Answer (score 19):

Just replace

```
 @Html.Raw(extra)
```

with

```
@(new HtmlString(extra))
```

Comment: nice and elegant solution

Comment: Answers like these need special attention and encouragement from SO community. Just saying.

Comment: This works well. Problem still exists in VS 2013 (FW 4.51)

Answer (score 5):

I think I know what's causing the issue...

The definition of the `Html` property getter is:

```
public static HtmlHelper Html {
    get { 
        WebPage currentWebPage = CurrentPage as WebPage;
        if (currentWebPage == null) {
            return null;
        } 
        return currentWebPage.Html;
    } 
}
```

Setting a breakpoint in my helper method shows that `CurrentPage` is not in fact an instance of `WebPage`, hence the `null` value.

Here is the type hierarchy of `CurrentPage` (my class names doctored slightly):

```
ASP._Page_Views_mycontroller_View_cshtml
  My.Site.MyWebViewPage`1
    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1
      System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
        System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase
          System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase
            System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase
              System.Object
```

Note that the base class of my view has been specified in Web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="My.Site.MyWebViewPage">
    ...
```

Which is defined both in generic and non-generic form:

```
public abstract class MyWebViewPage : WebViewPage { ... }
public abstract class MyWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> { ... }
```

So, if this problem does not occur for others, perhaps they're not using a custom `pageBaseType`.

Note too that I've placed the `@helper` declaration in `App_Code\Helpers.cshtml` in the hope of making it globally accessible.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

**EDIT** Thanks Darin for pointing out this as a known issue.  Still, why isn't the `Html` property redefined as:

```
public static HtmlHelper Html {
    get { 
        WebPage currentWebPage = CurrentPage as WebPage;
        if (currentWebPage != null) {
            return currentWebPage.Html;
        } 
        WebViewPage currentWebViewPage = CurrentPage as WebViewPage;
        if (currentWebViewPage != null) {
            return currentWebViewPage.Html;
        } 
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: it's not as straightforward. First of all, System.Web.WebPages.dll does not have a dependency on System.Web.Mvc.dll, so you can't have a reference to `WebViewPage`. Secondly, this `HtmlHelper` is actually a different type than the `HtmlHelper` in MVC, so this won't work. If it was this easy we certainly would have done it.

Comment: @marcind, fair enough.  I didn't expect I'd have dug as deeply as the team who built the API itself :)  I really like the idea of these declarative helpers, so whatever work can be done to support project-wide access and type parameters would be fantastic.

Comment: we certainly realize that the current story with helpers is insufficient and we plan on addressing that in the next version.

Comment: @marcind - glad to hear this will be addressed! In the meantime, does this mean that there is no way to have unencoded HTML in a declarative helper?  (short of passing in the HtmlHelper as a parameter which is kludgy)?  What would you suggest here?

Comment: @ChrisRogers: I've found that just using `new HtmlString` in place of `Html.Raw` works.

Comment: Well it's now 2015 and I'm using MVC5 and the Html helper is still null in declarative helpers.  I'm thinking I missed something somewhere, but it looks like it wasn't ever addressed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this line of code did the trick. It´s not a solution for using HtmlHelper, it's just a way of writing RAW html in a declarative razor helper.

```
@{CurrentPage.WriteLiteral("html code");}
```