# Html.BeginForm() in declarative helper methods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, razor-declarative-helpers

I'm trying to **create** a `from` using `Html.BeginForm()` in a razor helper method in a `partial page (Razor)` in `app_code` folder . but no success .

```
@helper  GenerateForm(...){

 @using(@Html.BeginForm(.... // error

}
```

I tried adding namespaces like `System.web.mvc` or `system.web.webpages` but no difference . 
**is it possible** to use this **method** in this **code** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the HtmlHelper instance null in a Razor declarative @helper method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282655/why-is-the-htmlhelper-instance-null-in-a-razor-declarative-helper-method)

Comment: HtmlHeLper is not null but it doesn't contain all the methods as it has in view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass HtmlHelper html to this helper and use it:

```
helper  GenerateForm(HtmlHelper html, ...){

    @using(html.BeginForm(.... // error

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : @using(Html.BeginForm(...

Comment: well, here is my example of a good code using htmlhlper:            @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        Select a file <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    </fieldset>
}