# Razor Missing Matching Closing Tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-table

I have some issues with a rather complex Table and Razor Tags.

I took the Most "@" out. (e.x. in front of the if etc.).

I played around for around 30 min and i can't seem to find the way to do it. I will always get error that  /  or similiar does not have any closing Tag. I played around with @: etc. but just can't get it.

If someone could help me out, and if someone could give a decent explanation of the @: tag, i'd highly appreciate that.

```
<div>
    if (Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        <table>
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 1)
                {
                    <tr class="tableEven">
                }
                else
                {
                    <tr class="tableOdd">
                }
                    @*Picture*@
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        <td rowspan="@Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows.Count" class="tblPicture"><img src="@Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]" /></td>
                    }
                    <td>
                        @Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                        @Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString()
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <text>Member Of:</text>
                        </td>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    for (int j = 0; j < Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[1].Rows.Count; j++)
                                    {
                                    if (j % 2 == 1)
                                    {
                                        <tr class="tableEven">
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <tr class="tableOdd">
                                    }
                                        <td rowspan="3">
                                            <div style="width: 400px; overflow-y: scroll">

                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                }
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

For anyone who would like to know, here is the fixed version:

```
<div>
    @if (Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        <table>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr class="@(i % 2 == 1 ? "tableEven" : "tableOdd")">
                    @if (i == 0)
                    {
                        <td rowspan="@Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows.Count" class="tblPicture"><img src="@Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]" /></td>
                    }
                    <td>
                        @Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                        @Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString()
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                    if (i == 5)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <text>Member Of:</text>
                        </td>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.dsInfoUser.Tables[1].Rows.Count; j++)
                                    {
                                        <tr class="@(i % 2 == 1 ? "tableEven" : "tableOdd")">
                                            <td rowspan="3">
                                                <div style="width: 400px; overflow-y: scroll">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                </table>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
            }
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Razor doesn't understand unclosed html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809694/razor-doesnt-understand-unclosed-html-tags)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it that way. Razor expects to be properly hierarchical. In particular, this is illegal:

```
if(condition)
{
    <foo>
}
else
{
    <foo>
}
</foo>
```

Even though we both know that would be a well-formed `<foo></foo>`, razor doesn't see it that way. It sees 2 unclosed `<foo>`, and a **completely unrelated** `</foo>` from nowhere.

In your case, the way to do this is:

```
<tr class="@(i % 2 == 1 ? "tableEven" : "tableOdd")">
   <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That's a flaw in Razor IMO. I don't expect Razor to be able to reason about complex logic, but here either the first block or the second block is going to run (unconditionally), so it should be able to understand. PhpStorm can reason about defined variables in this way, so Razor should be able too.

Comment: @Mark are you sure that isn't PhpStorm just being *simpler* and following the logic as it branches, simply doing what it is told in each branch? I.e. not really *figuring out* anything, but just being obedient?

Comment: What's the difference? If only one branch defines the variable it says "possibly undefined variable", but if they both have it then it doesn't raise a warning. Call it what you want, but this is intelligent behaviour.

Comment: @Mark indeed, razor will do that for "definite assignment", but I suspect *declaration* would be scoped accordingly. Different languages, different policies.

Comment: I don't understand. The tags will *definitely* match up here, so why can't it suppress the error? Is it a design decision, or the parser simply not that complex (yet)?

Comment: @Mark design decision; it wants constructs to be well-formed as nested entities, like XML

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i % 2 == 1)
{
    <tr class="tableEven">
}
else
{
    <tr class="tableOdd">
}
```

is probably what is giving you trouble

you should be able to rewrite it as

```
 string className = i%2 == 1 ? "tableEven" : "tableOdd"
 <tr class="@className">
```

and make the parser happy