# What is the proper way to disable a ReSharper HTML code inspection in a Razor page?

Tags: teamcity, resharper

I have a C# Razor page that ReSharper (via TeamCity Professional 2019.1.3, so [likely 2019.1.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/inspections-resharper.html#Inspections(ReSharper)-BundledReSharperVersions)) is flagging as having **Potential Code Quality Issues** > **Not closed tag**.

Since I'm only using the version of ReSharper that comes with TeamCity I need to manually add the code to ignore this error.

According to [the ReSharper documentation for Potential Code Quality issues](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Inspections_HTML.html#CodeSmell) the ID is `Html.TagNotClosed`, which means that I should be able to use the following comment above the code that's triggering this error: `ReSharper disable once Html.TagNotClosed`

However, if I try either of the following code snippets ReSharper does not ignore this error.

```
@if (currentRecord % 3 == 1)
{
    // ReSharper disable once Html.TagNotClosed
    <text><div class="row top-spacing-none bottom-spacing-small" data-equalizer="" data-equalizer-mq="medium-up"></text>
}

// alternative

@if (currentRecord % 3 == 1)
{
    <!-- ReSharper disable once Html.TagNotClosed -->
    <text><div class="row top-spacing-none bottom-spacing-small" data-equalizer="" data-equalizer-mq="medium-up"></text>
}
```

I've confirmed that this is the line it's throwing an error on, and this is the code I want to try, due to the issue covered by [Razor doesn't understand unclosed html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809694/razor-doesnt-understand-unclosed-html-tags).

What's the proper way to have ReSharper ignore a 'Not closed tag' error in a Razor CSHTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's impossible to disable this particular highlighting with "disable once". At least because it happens twice. You can do one of the following: 
 1. Use disable/restore instead:

```
// ReSharper disable Html.TagNotClosed
<text><div class="row top-spacing-none bottom-spacing-small" data-equalizer="" data-equalizer-mq="medium-up"></text>
// ReSharper restore Html.TagNotClosed
```

2. Use `@:`, ReSharper skips "tag not closed" analysis in it

```
@: <div class="row top-spacing-none bottom-spacing-small" data-equalizer="" data-equalizer-mq="medium-up">
```

Comment: First option worked great. I a) didn't even think about those comments for some reason and b) guess I would have expected the error count to drop from 2 on this line to one if I disabled it once. Thanks for the easy solution!

Comment: Yep, b) is a bug, would be fixed soon