# Blazor App Not Using Nested If Statements Properly

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I know, I suck because I am using a `table` and not `div` tags but I could not get the `div` tags to display properly and my deadline was some time last week...

I am trying to layout a bunch of devices along with their statuses and other simple options and yet I cannot get the `ìf` statements to work.  Here is my code:

```html
@if (CurrentSystem == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    @foreach (Device thisDevice in CurrentSystem.LocalDevices)
    {
        menuCounter++;
        divCounter++;

        if (divCounter == 1)
        {
            //Starting with the first column
            <tr><td class=cardBox>
        }
        else
        {
            //Starting with the last column
            <tr><td class=outSideColumns></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class=cardBox>
        }

        targetName = "target" + @menuCounter;
        targetNameWithDot = "." + @targetName;
        menuId = "contextMenu" + @menuCounter;
        modalID = "modalWindow" + @menuCounter;

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="targetName" style="text-align:right;justify-content:right;">
                        <a href="#" class="menuButton">...</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <h3>
                        thisDevice.DeviceName
                    </h3>
                    <img src="@ReturnDeviceImage(thisDevice)" class=deviceImage />
                    @if (thisDevice.CurrentStatus == Device.DeviceStatus.Alert)
                    {
                        <h4 Class="cardAlert">Status: Alert</h4>
                    }
                    else if (thisDevice.CurrentStatus == Device.DeviceStatus.Inactive)
                    {
                        <h4 Class="cardInactive">Status: Inactive</h4>
                    }
                    else if (thisDevice.CurrentStatus == Device.DeviceStatus.Unknown)
                    {
                        <h4 Class="cardUnknown">Status: Unknown</h4>
                    }
                    else if (thisDevice.CurrentStatus == Device.DeviceStatus.Normal)
                    {
                        <h4 Class=cardNormal>Status: Normal</h4>
                    }
                    else if (thisDevice.CurrentStatus == Device.DeviceStatus.Updating)
                    {
                        <h4 Class=cardUpdating>Status: Normal</h4>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <h4>Status: thisDevice.CurrentStatus</h4>
                    }
                    <TelerikContextMenu IdField="@menuId" Selector="@targetNameWithDot" Data="@MenuItems" OnClick="@((ContextMenuItem item) => OnItemClick(item, @thisDevice.DeviceIDHash))">
                    </TelerikContextMenu>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=nameDivs>
                    Device Type:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @thisDevice.DeviceType
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=nameDivs>
                    Hostname:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @thisDevice.DeviceHostname
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=nameDivs>
                    Communications:
                </td>
                    @if (thisDevice.UsingEncryption)
                    {
                        <td class=cardNormal>Are Encrypted</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td> class=cardAlert>Are Not Encrypted</td>
                    }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=nameDivs>
                    Anomaly Response Level:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @thisDevice.AnomalyResponse
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        if (divCounter == 1)
        {
            //Ending the first column
           </td>
            <td></td>
            <td class=outSideColumns></td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            //Ending the last column
            </td></tr>
            divCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    </table>
}
```

The beginning `if` statement and the `if` statements that run the `CurrentStatus` and `UsingEncryption` seem to be working, however the last `if` statement is simply writing text to the screen.

- If I add `@` signs to the first and/or last `if` statements, I get a ton
  of errors about not having closing tags, objects not being defined,
  etc...
- If I remove the `@` signs from the `CurrentStatus` and `UsingEncryption` `if`
  statements, those statements stop working.
- If I remove the `@` from the `foreach` statement, nothing prints out.

What am I doing wrong?!?

Comment: Firstly I see one opening `<table>` but two closing `</table>`.  That's not going to fly with the Razor compiler.  Also all `if`s need to be declared as  `@if`.  If the compiler doesn't like it then you have code errors.  Remove/comment out blocks until you find your problems.

Comment: `@if` is the only correct `if`. Fix the other errors.

Comment: You cannot render partial tags like you are doing in the first `if`. Blazor will close these elements for you ` <tr><td class=cardBox>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use tag helpers, your html structure must mirror your control flow. You can't just start a tag inside an if test without also closing it within that if test.

While you can escape unmatched html tags with `@:` (eg [Razor doesn't understand unclosed html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809694/razor-doesnt-understand-unclosed-html-tags/19413999)), with a little effort, you can eliminate your unmatched tags;

```cs
            <tr>
            @if(divCounter != 1)
            {
                //Starting with the last column
                <td class=outSideColumns></td>
                <td></td>
            }
            <td class=cardBox>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that was it!

Answer (score -1):

While Jeremy provided an excellent answer.  I ended up running into issues where I absolutely needed open tags and, in fact, I had to re-write everything back into DIV tags to make things work.

That is when I discovered my new bestest friend - the MarkupString - that I can use to insert any HTML code I desire without blowing up the IDE!

Here is a link that explains how to use it - https://www.meziantou.net/rendering-raw-unescaped-html-in-blazor.htm