# Can't get Razor if statement to work properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got the following simple code:

```
@for (int j = 0; j < file.Items.Count; j++) {
var item = file.Items[j];
if (item.Errors.Count > 0)
{
    Html.Raw("<tr class='errors'>");
}
else {
    Html.Raw("<tr>");
}
    <td>blah</td>
    </tr>
}
```

However, I keep getting a parsing error saying that the closing `</tr>` has no opening tag.  What am I missing?  If I replace the if statement with a regular `<tr>` then it works fine.

Comment: Are you closing the for loop with a }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is just an intellisense problem, try this hack:

```
@for (int j = 0; j < file.Items.Count; j++) {
   var item = file.Items[j];
   if (item.Errors.Count > 0)
   {
       @:<tr class="errors">
   }
   else {
       @:"<tr>");
   }
       @:<td>blah</td>
       @:</tr>
 }
```

I think your code is perfectly OK, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781896/razor-view-engine-complex-looping-and-html) SO question for great explanations of this.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try losing the Html.Raw in both cases. I don't see why you need them